# Filling missing data in a data set with constant values

Tags: arrays, matlab, constants

I have a data set like the following:

```
x= [1, 4, 10]
y= [10, 20, 30]
```

(x and y are value pairs, i.e. (1,10), (4,20), (10,30))

I would like to fill the x values gaps and having constant values for y until the next known value pair comes.This should be done between each value pair, i.e. between (1,10) and (4,20) and then again between (4,20) and (10,30).

Input:

```
x=[1, 4, 10];
y=[10, 20, 30];
```

Output:

```
xi= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
yi= [10,10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30];
```

How can Matlab solve this for me?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming ascending order of elements in `x`, this could be one approach based on [`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) & [`cumsum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) -

```
%// Sample inputs
x=[1, 4, 10]
y=[-2, 5, -3]

xi = min(x):max(x)
yi = zeros(1,numel(xi))
yi(x) = diff([0 y])
yi = cumsum(yi)
```

Sample run -

```
x =
     1     4    10
y =
    -2     5    -3
xi =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
yi =
    -2    -2    -2     5     5     5     5     5     5    -3
```

---

*Customary* [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) solution to get `yi` -

```
lens = [diff(x) 1];
yi = nonzeros(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@ge,lens,[1:max(lens)]'),y)).'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x` always starts with a 1 and finishes with the final length of `xi`, this will work:

```
xi=1:x(end)
yi=y(arrayfun(@(xi)find(x<=xi,1,'last'),xi))
```